# postfix senders name partially missing due to comma

Tags: email, configuration, postfix-mta

All user names in /etc/passwd are formatted "**Lastname, Firstname**"
E.G

```
~# getent passwd jbloggs
jbloggs:*:1367239261:1367200513:Bloggs, Joe:/home/jbloggs:/bin/bash
```

When an email is sent by Joe Bloggs (or Bloggs, Joe as listed in the passwd file) recipients of the email see the email coming from:
**Bloggs** <jbloggs@comany.com>
it should be:
**Bloggs, Joe** <jbloggs@comany.com>

When I remove the comma for Joe in passwd I see:
**Bloggs Joe** <jbloggs@comany.com>

This seems like a simple settings change but despite my searches I cannot find how to correct this.
Any help appreciated.